# Allowing line set colors to initially be the same

Tags: java, colors, processing

I have this program that does most everything I want it to do except for one issue, and it's really quite a small one. When the line sets and boxes for color initially appear they are all white as initialized. However, when you change each one by clicking on a box they all change to separate colors. To get them to all change to the same color you have to loop once through them all. I'd like all the color boxes to be the same color from the beginning without having to loop through, but I'm not sure why the way I have it set up doesn't allow for that. I'd appreciate any suggestions for correction.

```
final int arraySize = 4;
int counter;

Button[] b = new Button[arraySize];
int[] flag = new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1};
boolean[] show = new boolean[arraySize];
char[] keys = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4'};
color[] cols = new color[] {#F6546A, #FFC390, #FFF68F, #D3FFCE, #C6E2FF, #D2B4FF, #FFFFFF, };
color[] c = new color[]{#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF};

void setup() {
  size(800, 700);
  counter = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    b[i] = new Button(20, 160+(40*i), 20, 20);
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (show[i]) {
      b[i].draw_button(c[i]);
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (key == keys[i] && flag[i] == 1) {
      show[i] = true;
      flag[i] = flag[i]*-1;
    } else if (key == keys[i] && flag[i] == -1) {
      show[i] = false;
      flag[i] = flag[i]*-1;
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (b[i].mouse_is_over() == true ) {
      c[i] = cols[counter];
      counter++;
    }
    if (counter == cols.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
}

class Button{
  float x, y, w, h;

  Button(float xpos, float ypos, float width_, float height_){
    x = xpos; y = ypos;
    w = width_; h = height_;
  }

  void draw_button(color c){
    fill(c);
    stroke(255);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  boolean mouse_is_over(){
    return (mouseX > x && mouseX < (x+w) && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y+h));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to loop through them all? Looping is generally exactly how you would reset a bunch of variables. Also, could you post a [mcve] instead of your entire sketch?

Comment: the Equation class gives you the movement and position of the lines?

Comment: I suggest, you put the `drawlines` method inside your `Equation` class and give it just a `color myColor` parameter for the `stroke`, so you can do `set.drawlines(color)`, sience all the other parameters in your current function are part of the `Equation` object.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code so that it just deals with the color part. You press 1, 2, 3, and 4 keys to get the boxes to show up. If you notice, the first time you click on a box it will to the first color, then the next box will change to the second. It's not until you go through all the colors once with each box that you can set them all as the same color. I just wanted to allow for that from the start. @Cr1xus, I'll try out your idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your `counter` variable is outside your `Button` instances. So if you click the first button, your `counter` variable goes up to `1`, and you use that to set the first button's color. Then when you click the second button, your `counter` variable goes up to `2`, and you use that to set the second button's color. The same thing happens as you click other buttons: clicking one button affects the next color of all of the other buttons.

If you want each button to have its own color sequence, then you would want each `Button` instance to have its own `counter`. In other words, you would want to move the `counter` variable to be inside the `Button` class.

Then whenever you use the `counter` variable, you would have to use the `counter` variable of a particular `Button` instance.

While you're at it, you might want to move some of the other variables inside your `Button` class. The `c` array could be a single variable inside the `Button` class that keeps track of the current color of a `Button` instance, or you could get rid of it since you can just use the `counter` variable anyway. Similarly, the `flag` array could just be a `boolean` variable inside the `Button` class.

Comment: How would counter keep up with the color? I need c to initially set each color to white and then pass the colors as the increment. I'm still going to have to store all the separate colors somewhere, which is what cols is for. Unless I pass cols[6] each time initially and then pass the counter back from the button class to change cols.

Comment: @philxyz You have a sketch-level array of colors. Each `Button` instance would just store an index into that array to keep track of its color. Increment that index when you click the button.

Comment: So, I attempted to implement what you said. I posted it in my op under "attempting to fix issue". I'm confused because it seems like you would need to pass the `counter` back from the `Button` class in order to implement `cols[]` at the sketch level. Which is what I attempted to do, but it's not allowing me to do that. I imagine you had something different in mind, but I'm just not following, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Workman

I realized that I didn't actually need to pass the counter, just internalize it in the class as you said.

```
final int arraySize = 4;

Button[] b = new Button[arraySize];
int[] flag = new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1};
boolean[] show = new boolean[arraySize];
char[] keys = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4'};


void setup() {
  size(800, 700);

  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    b[i] = new Button(20, 160+(40*i), 20, 20);
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (show[i]) {
      b[i].draw_button();
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (key == keys[i] && flag[i] == 1) {
      show[i] = true;
      flag[i] = flag[i]*-1;
    } else if (key == keys[i] && flag[i] == -1) {
      show[i] = false;
      flag[i] = flag[i]*-1;
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
      b[i].mouse_is_over();
  }
}

class Button{
  color[] cols = new color[] {#FFFFFF, #F6546A, #FFC390, #FFF68F, #D3FFCE, #C6E2FF, #D2B4FF,};
  float x, y, w, h;
  int counter;

  Button(float xpos, float ypos, float width_, float height_){
    x = xpos; y = ypos;
    w = width_; h = height_;
    counter = 0;
  }

  void draw_button(){
    fill(cols[counter]);
    stroke(255);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  void mouse_is_over(){
    if(mouseX > x && mouseX < (x+w) && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y+h)){
      counter++;
      counter = counter%cols.length;
    }
  }
}
```